In high contrast mode only the "Cookie settings" link in the footer is underlined
When high contrast is enabled, usually all links are underlined.
Except for the footer where they are not underlined.
Except for "Cookie settings" which is underlined.


It's a button instead of a link! The wonders of this site :)

@Gimby clicking on "Cookie settings" opens up a modal rather than a different page so I'd say making it an anchor won't make much sense.

It not being an actual link has caused other bugs, e.g. The "Cookie Settings" link in the footer is not aligned vertically with the other links in the "Company" section on narrow screens

@AbdulAzizBarkat the fact that they make it look exactly like a link begs to differ.
